# Material-UI-Next Single Line Grid List doesn't have a horizontal scrollbar like it does in the example component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

https://material-ui-next.com/demos/grid-list/#single-line-grid-list

If I copy and paste this code into my project I get the same grid list sans the horizontal scrollbar. I can still scroll with touch controls in dev tools or click my mouse wheel, but that scrollbar is important for my project.

Anyone know of any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the Drawer Component removes the scollbar. Will do further tests on my own.